# In bash: a "sed" command of a $VARIABLE inside a for loop

Tags: python, bash, variables, for-loop, sed

I have a file that has these lines:

```
s17 line linewidth 1.0
s18 line linewidth 1.0
.
.
.
s28 line linewidth 1.0
```

I would like to replace these lines by:

```
 s17 line linewidth 2.0
 s18 line linewidth 2.0
 .
 .
 .
 s28 line linewidth 2.0
```

I have written this code in bash:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for VARIABLE in {17..28}
 do
   sed 's/s${VARIABLE} line linewidth 1\.0/s${VARIABLE} line linewidth 2\.0/g' ./band-structure-calcite.agr
 done
```

Then I run the code by making `bash change.sh > changed.txt` but the file `changed.txt` does not contain these modifications.

I would appreciate very much if you help me and explain me the syntax of your code answers as I am learning bash

Comment: Single quotes don't interpolate variables, double quotes do.

Comment: Running `sed` N times is inefficient and going to give you many duplicate output lines (N copies of every line with *one* of each copy modified appropriately). If you just want to change `1.0` to `2.0` on lines that match those numbers (and presumably not others) there are better ways to do this.

Comment: @choroba : I have changed the script to: `sed "s/s${VARIABLE} line linewidth 1\.0/s${VARIABLE} line linewidth 2\.0/g" ./band-structure-calcite.agr` and it does not work

Comment: @EtanReisner :... " If you just want to change `1.0` to `2.0` on lines that match those numbers (and presumably not others)" ... No, I would like to change the string `s17 line linewidth 1.0` by `s17 line linewidth 2.0`; `s18 line linewidth 1.0` by `s18 line linewidth 2.0` and so on as showed above. The integers that appear to the right of the string `s` change from `17` to `28`: `s17, s18, s19 ... s28`

Comment: Yes, but you aren't changing the `s##` part of the line just the `1.0` to `2.0`, no? So the rest of your matching, etc. isn't doing much unless there are *other* lines with `s##` values wher eyou *don't* want to change the `1.0`.

Comment: @EtanReisner : Yes, there are other lines with `s##` values where I don't want to change the `1.0`. That is why in the for loop I am only running from `17` to `28`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than running `sed` several times, generate a sed script in the loop and run it once:

```
for n in {17..28} ; do
    echo "s/s$n line linewidth 1\.0/s$n line linewidth 2.0/g"
done | sed -f- ./band-structure-calcite.agr > changed.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, but I need to understand the code...
 the line: `echo "s/s$n line linewidth 1\.0/s$n line linewidth 2.0/g"` 
prints:  `s/s17 line linewidth 1\.0/s17 line linewidth 2\.0/g`

            `s/s18 line linewidth 1\.0/s18 line linewidth 2\.0/g`

             `.`

             `.`
             
              `.`

Then you finish the loop with `done` followed by `| sed -f- filename` . Now, what does  `| sed -f- filename` mean? Thanks again :)

Comment: @DavidC.: It calls sed that interprets the output of the loop as its script.

Answer (score 1):

Make a regular expression with your numbers:

```
allnr=""
for nr in {17..28}
do
    allnr+="${nr}|"
done
# Debug: echo "allnr=${allnr%|}"
sed -r 's/s('"${allnr%|}"') line linewidth 1\.0/s\1 line linewidth 2.0/g' ./band-structure-calcite.agr
```

Comment: Thanks for  your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the loop with a regular expression in the address part of the sed command:

```
'/^s\(\(1[7-9]\)\|\(2[0-8]\)\)\s/ s/1\.0$/2.0/' ./band-structure-calcite.agr
```

The regular expression (`/^s\(\(1[7-9]\)\|\(2[0-8]\)\)\s/`) matches lines beginning with s17, s18, ... or s28, followed by a space or tab, and `sed` applies the following `s/1\.0$/2.0/` command only to those lines.  Other lines pass through unchanged.  The whole file is read through exactly once, and the output contains one output line per input line, unlike your original.